# RuntimeError: CUDA error - Initialization error in PyTorch DataLoader worker process

Tags: python, pytorch, google-colaboratory

I am encountering a RuntimeError in my PyTorch code while using a DataLoader for training. The error occurs in the worker process, and the traceback points to a CUDA initialization error. The specific message is:

```
RuntimeError: Caught RuntimeError in DataLoader worker process 0.
Original Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/worker.py", line 308, in _worker_loop
    data = fetcher.fetch(index)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py", line 51, in fetch
    data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py", line 51, in <listcomp>
    data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
  File "<ipython-input-38-b0835867e243>", line 8, in __getitem__
    return self.X[index], self.Y[index]
RuntimeError: CUDA error: initialization error
Compile with `TORCH_USE_CUDA_DSA` to enable device-side assertions.
```

```py
# Code snippet where the error occurs
for batch, (X, Y) in enumerate(train_dataloader): <---- error here 
    print(f"Batch: {batch+1}")
    print(f"X shape: {X.shape}")
```

I am using PyTorch for a deep learning project and is only occurring when I try to iterate over the data loader. The error seems to be related to CUDA initialization, but I'm not sure how to address it.

I'm running on Google Colab with:
PyTorch version: 2.1.0+cu121 
GPU model: Tesla T4

I set the device with the following bit of code:
`device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")`
and it does grab the GPU. I'm handing the device to tensors on initialization, which happens in a test/train split function.

I tried setting TORCH_USE_CUDA_DSA with `os.environ["TORCH_USE_CUDA_DSA"] = "1"`, but didn't manage to get anything working from that.
What does the error mean/why does it happen? It works fine when my torch device is set to 'cpu', so it's not a problem with the overall data ingestion/training.

The data class is pretty simple:

```py
class Data(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, X, Y):
        self.X = X
        self.Y = Y
        self.len = len(X)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.X[index], self.Y[index]

    def __len__(self):
        return self.len
```

I set up the data loader with the use of the GPU in mind:

```py
batch_size = 256

train_data = Data(X_train, Y_train)
train_dataloader = DataLoader(
  dataset=train_data, 
  batch_size=batch_size, 
  shuffle=True,
  pin_memory=True
)


# Check it's working
for batch, (X, Y) in enumerate(train_dataloader): <--- error
    print(f"Batch: {batch+1}")
    print(f"X shape: {X.shape}")
    print(f"y shape: {Y.shape}")
    print(f"X type: {X.dtype}")
    print(f"Y type: {Y.dtype}")
    break
```

Weirdly enough, when I remove the num_workers and pin_memory params, it works. These are valuable for improving training runtime, but maybe I'm misusing them? Not sure what the deal is there.

Is there a way to set TORCH_USE_CUDA_DSA?

Comment: Do you happen to set the device (send your data to the cuda device) inside the dataloader `__getitem__` method?

Comment: @Ivan No, I set the device when doing my test/train split. I hand a split function the data as python arrays and then return the split data as tensors that are given the device. 
torch.tensor(split_data, device=device, dtype=torch.float32)
Not sure if this is standard practice, but not seeing why it would break things.

Comment: Could you please share more about the dataset class in your code or __getitem__()? I recommend replacing CUDA with CPU to get a better error message.

Comment: @Hamzah the dataset is just a series of midi node pitches ranging from 0 to 127. The data class is as follows:
class Data(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, X, Y):
        self.X = X
        self.Y = Y
        self.len = len(X)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.X[index], self.Y[index]

    def __len__(self):
        return self.len

And I don't get any errors when replacing CUDA with CPU. It just works, which is why I'm so confused about this

Comment: So it seems you are transferring data from within the dataloader. Please provide the code where you are transferring to cuda, is it inside the `__getitem__`?

Answer (score 0):

To see where the error comes from run it on cpu by setting the `device = torch.device("cpu")`. After solving the issue you can switch the device back to cuda